# Реализация древовидной структуры laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

На данный момент имеется таблица `pdfs (id, version, parent_id)` и модель `App\Pdf`.

При создании новой записи в таблице, вручную добавляю в модель в поле `parent_id` текущий ID, а в версию сохраняется `null`. Возникла необходимость добавить в эту структуру возможность изменения данных, при этом, к примеру, изменяя PDF-файл с ID 5, мы должны получить следующую запись в БД: `id = *increment*, version = 1, parent_id = 5`. Т.е. мы делаем дочернюю запись, связывая поле по `parent_id`.

Понимаю, что это костыль. Как правильнее реализовать древовидную структуру с максимальной вложенностью в 1 шаг, но при этом с генерацией id в виде 5.1, 5.2 и т.д. ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать поле **parent_data** и положите туда **json_encode** данных.
А далее распарсите как Вам нужно.